# Jquery onclick for anything inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know this is pretty easy, and I am probably missing something very obvious, but here it goes.

I have an `<ul>` with a bunch of stuff inside.

I have set jquery, so that when `<ul>` is clicked, to assign it a class name, but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#list').click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(this).addClass('left');
    });
});
```

It works however, if the `<ul>` is wider than the stuff in it, and I click where there is no stuff.

Here is the HTML

```
 <ul id="list">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="pos1">
            <span class="ei_preview"></span>
            <span class="ei_image"></span>
          </a>
          <div class="ei_descr">
            <h2>Name</h2>
            <h3>Last Name</h3>
            <p>
           Herp derp derp, hurr durr
            </p>
            <p>
           Herp derp derp, hurr durr
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="pos2">
            <span class="ei_preview"></span>
            <span class="ei_image"></span>
          </a>
          <div class="ei_descr">
            <h2>Name</h2>
            <h3>Last name</h3>
            <p>
           Herp derp derp, hurr durr
            </p>
            <p>
            Herp derp derp, hurr durr
            </p>
          </div>

        </li>
</ul>
```

EDIT: 
After looking at the CSS, when I click a `<li>`, it doesn't work for the `<ul>` because `<li>` is set as `position: relative;`. Any idea how to overcome this without removing the position property ?

CSS as requested : http://hastebin.com/pahaxexabo.css

The `.left` is the class I want to assign to the `<ul>`.

Comment: I think your problem is with CSS of the UL

Comment: why do you say it doesn't work? Code works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/2kXCp/

Answer (score 1):

Well without the html, its hard to debug your javascript.

Looking at your java script, your function will trigger when an element with id 'list' is clicked.

Does your ul tag have the attribute id="list"  ?

If you want clicking of any ul tags to trigger the event, change the 2nd line in your jquery to the following:

```
...
$('ul').click(function(event) {
...
```

Also, im unsure why you need this code below, it looks like it is superfluous

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

You javascript appears to be fine.  The problem likely resides with your css.  Try writing your HTML with the class you are adding already added and check if the ul has the desired style.  Once it has the desired css style, then attempt using the jquery again.

Comment: There, added the markup, and `event.stopPropagation();` is there just because I was trying to fix this.

Comment: check your css and remove the event.stopPropagation

Comment: I edited the OP, please check that. I found the source of the problem, but don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I don't have the same issue as you: works fine with me.  Have you checked your entire javascript for errors?  I recommend using firefox and then looking at the error console to check if there is perhaps a javascript error elsewhere on the page that is causing everything to fail

Comment: Lol. I found the problem. It just doesn't work when I click on the `<li>` tags because they're absolutely positioned. I just need to find a way around this without removing the positioning.